# Combining external feed into post loop

Tags: loop, feed

I don't even know where to start on this.

I would like to combine an external JSON or XML feed into the post loop and sort it by date. The page will need to auto-load the next posts and have the ability to filter by category.

I'm not sure if the best way to do this is to create a custom post type for this external feed and create a post for each item.

Comment: You want to inject posts from an external source into an existing loop?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was CURLing down the external feed and then merging arrays together.